# What is the Best way to use Microsoft exchange in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, ms-exchange

What is the best way to use Microsoft exchange in Ubuntu 17.04 fluently? Is it  possible to use Thunderbird for this free of cost?

Comment: That also depends on the settings of MS-E: if it includes support for the SMTP and IMAP protocols Thunderbird will work.

Answer (score 5):

I find that [Evolution](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/evolution) with [EWS Plugin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/evolution-ews/) works well with Microsoft Exchange.

```
sudo apt-get install evolution evolution-ews
```

Answer (score 1):

Hiri is a fast, secure, efficient mail client for those that want to access Exchange / Office 365 on Linux. You can use Hiri to connect to Exchange, Office365, or a Microsoft email account (Outlook.com, Live, Hotmail). Other email providers, such as Gmail, Yahoo, etc. are currently not supported. Hiri can be installed from the Ubuntu Software app in Ubuntu 16.04 and later.

- Beautiful, uncluttered interface helps you blaze through your emails.
- Unique Skills Center that helps you get your email under control.
- Fully functional calendar.
- Syncs your emails, calendars, tasks and contacts.
- Access your company’s Global Address List.
- Your mail does not pass through any 3rd party servers - strictly between you and your server.
- Uses Microsoft’s EWS protocol - works with Exchange as it should.

Hiri is a paid for app, but you get a 7 day free trial. If nothing else if you install Hiri and try the free trial, you'll get to see how a paid for app like Hiri compares to a free app like Evolution.

- [Hiri channel on vimeo.com](https://vimeo.com/user16166704)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share a complete 3-Step tutorial to sync your calendar account with Linux.

**Note:** This will also sync your email to evolution, after the tutorial just open evolution and refresh the mailbox - you must have email sync enable on **Online Accounts**.

This tutorial will even work with personalized enterprise domain in office 365.

**STEP 1)** Install **evolution-ews** on your Linux

**Debian and derivated:**

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-ews
```

or just

```
sudo apt install evolution-ews
```

on newer versions.

**Fedora and Derivated:**

```
sudo yum install evolution-ews
```

or

```
sudo dnf install evolution-ews
```

on newer versions.

**STEP 2)** On **Online Accounts** select **Microsoft Exchange**:

Fill up the email and password fields with your Office 365 info (the rest will be filled automatically).

STEP 3) Replace **Server** field with:

```
outlook.office365.com
```

and copy the **email** field content into **username** field.

Here is how it should look like:

**BEFORE:**
[image: Before]

**AFTER:**
[image: After]

If any error occurs on connecting to Microsoft exchange:

- go to the browser and log in to your Microsoft account
- go to the accounts section and in the security info tab add a sign-in method
- choose **App password** and use that password with your email in Microsoft exchange to sign in.